# pandas.Series.fillna change type of the column

Tags: python, pandas, types, series

After changing type of columns in `pandas.DataFrame` from `int64` to `object`, `fillna`, applied to this column, returns columns with `int64` type again. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [2, 3]})

# changing type to 'object'
data['a'] = data['a'].astype('object')
print("type after astype -", data['a'].dtype)

# applying fillna
data["a"] = data["a"].fillna("no data")
print("type after fillna -", data['a'].dtype)
```

Will return:

```
type after astype - object
type after fillna - int64
```

How fix it, without using `astype` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `downcast=False` to prevent this:

```
data['a'].fillna('no data', downcast=False)
```